# excel formula for same data but highest number

Tags: excel-formula

I need to know the formula for my data like this :

```
A     B      C
234   5
234   4
234   2
255   6
255   3
266   2
266   1
```

I want to mark same column C with 1 to those having same number in A but highest number in B. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for

[find max min value based on criteria](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2683-excel-find-max-min-value-based-on-criteria.html)